# Adding extra data to serialized form via ajax call

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a problem with adding extra data to my serialized form string.
Basically I have an form which has a group of fields called "Services", and the user can add how many services he wants. I add dynamically services inputs via button in the interface. So my problem is when I want to add them to the other fields (serialized form). I add these inputs to array of objects. For the example I will just create them manually.

Here is my code:

```
var form = mainContainer.find('form');
    var seriliazedForm = form.serialize();
    var url = me.resolveUrl(form[0].action);
    if (url == "XXXX") {
        var services = [];
        services.push({ ServiceId: '1', Service: "paint", Description: 'yellow', Price: '5' });
        services.push({ ServiceId: '2', Service: "paint2", Description: 'yellow', Price: '6' });
        seriliazedForm = seriliazedForm + "&" + $.param({ 'Services': services });
    }

 $.ajax({
            type: auto.ajax.POST,
            url: url,
            data: seriliazedForm 
        });
```

So I want to bind these 'Services' to the url so when I post to the method I can
see them in the ViewModel.The viewModel have member called :

```
public List<ServiceViewModel> Services { get; set; }
```

So the result I want is to see the services like in the picture in the controller method:

[image]

What I have tried already ( reading all possible solutions in stack and other resources), but there was no result:

1.

```
var seriliazedForm = seriliazedForm + "&" + $.param({ 'Services': services });
```

2.

```
var seriliazedForm = seriliazedForm + "&" + $(services).serializeArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to continue to use the jQuery method [$.param](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) you need to change the way to build the **params** to send via ajax:

```
var seriliazedForm = form.serializeArray();
seriliazedForm.push({ name: '1', value: JSON.stringify({ServiceId: '1', Service: "paint", Description: 'yellow', Price: '5' })});
seriliazedForm.push({ name: '2', value: JSON.stringify({ServiceId: '2', Service: "paint2", Description: 'yellow', Price: '6'})});
var formData = $.param(seriliazedForm);
```

And remember to set to false [contentType and processData](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) in the ajax call.

The main change is on how you can add new elements to the form data. Because each new element should be in the form:

```
{name: ...., value:....}
```

You need to convert your objects in something like a couple name/value.

A second way is based on using [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) and the method append:

```
var formData = new FormData(form.get(0));
formData.append('ServiceId1', { ServiceId: '1', Service: "paint", Description: 'yellow', Price: '5' });
formData.append('ServiceId2', { ServiceId: '2', Service: "paint2", Description: 'yellow', Price: '6' });
```

Finally, your ajax call will look like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'z.html',
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
 });
```

Comment: I tried both of these ways,but there wasn't a result,because I have already some form with inputs in it and when I tried the first scenario they didnt post to the controller ( i add the content type and process data ) .Can you tell me is there any chance i can send the list separately from the form?

Comment: Because you are using POST, are you sure you get correctly the data on the server?  I assume you confuse GET and POST.  In any case, i suggest to use POST because a query string is limited. Moreover,  i divided your array in two,  you may consider to send it as one element,  a minor change. Let me know.  Thanks

Comment: @razi3lbr  Take a look to the following [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/mz7gLw94/2/).